# Do http file downloads download byte sequentially?

Tags: bash, google-chrome, split

So I have a couple GiB tgz archive I'm downloading from my server, I was wondering if Google Chrome is downloading the first byte, writing it, then moving onto the second byte or just getting random pieces.

Basically the file is taking forever and I used Split on the server side version (after I started downloading) to create 200MiB pieces.  I really wanna know if I can take the partially downloaded file from Google Chrome and split it locally into the same sized pieces and just match up the pieces from the server that I need.

Comment: HTTP is sequential. To solve your problem, you should just use a download manager that will "multi-thread" the download by requesting it 8 (or whatever) times concurrently, with a different byte offset for each: see the `Range` header.

Comment: @thirtydot it's campus internet throttles, more connections over the same protocol slow it down, so I have one over http and one over SSH

Comment: @thirtydot, http provides random access: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35

Comment: @Snowbear: No, it allows you to start *sequentially* downloading from an arbitrary byte offset. I already mentioned the `Range` header.

Comment: @thirtydot: What's the difference between random access and sequentielly downloading from an arbitrary byte offset? I can download 1 byte pieces if I want, so it's random access, isn't it?

Comment: @schnaader: To do that, you have to either specify a massive `Range` header with a list of all the single bytes you want, or make zillions of round trips to the server starting new downloads with separate `Range` requests. Downloading a `"couple GiB tgz archive"` like this would be *very inefficient*, and that's what we're talking about here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try splitting the partially downloaded file and then compare local pieces with corresponding pieces on server by comparing their hashes. It seems to be easier than guessing how Chrome handles it.

Comment: this will prolly be a dumb question but is their a quick hash command in bash?

Comment: @Greg: `md5sum [filename]`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, browsers handle download sequentially. However, you can use add-on/extension download managers, I'm sure there are many for Chrome, too. These often will use multiple connections to load different parts of a file and are able to pause/resume downloads.

Comment: I'm limited by the campus internet speeds, they throttle us for downloading too much and even before the throttle (~50kbps) we're limited to 250kbps, on http, my way around is using SSH and HTTP, so those are the only 2 connections i can do

Comment: Using a download manager doesn't change the protocal AFAIK, so it should still be HTTP traffic... It just uses advanced HTTP requests to get specific parts of the file ( see http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.35 ).

Answer (score 0):

On the command line you could try mcurl:

```
"Multiple cURL" is a shell script to download files in multiple parts via cURL...
```

http://www.goforlinux.de/scripts/mcurl/